# What are the parameters used while generating CAVV & XID values at issuer ACS?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

How the validation will take place at VISA?

**First part of my question**: What are the parameters that are considered by any issuer ACS system while calculating XID & CAVV values for a verified by VISA transaction (3d secure transaction). To start off, i'm aware that networks do provide a local key for each issuer with which the value can be encrypted, but what are the other parameters that are considered while generating these values?

**Second part** : What are the values that are specific to a cardholder are used while validating the XID & CAVV at Verified by VISA site? I want to understand how the process flows for validation of these values.

Any reference links related to these questions would help.

Comment: Hi Surya, since posted very long, may I ask whether you managed to get the algorithm and if so share it here, please?